# How many $\mathbb Z[[X]]^\times$-orbits are there in $\mathbb Z[[X]]$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, set-theory

Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z[[X]]$, where $X$ is an determinate, and let $S$ be the set of $G$-orbits in $\mathbb Z[[X]]$.

> What is the cardinal of $S$?

In view of the references below, we have (with obvious notation)
$$
\text{card}(\mathbb N)\le\text{card}(S)\le\text{card}(\mathbb R).
$$

**References**

$\bullet$ Integral Domains Arising as Quotient Rings of $\mathbb Z[[x]]$; James M. McDonough

http://repository.library.csuci.edu/bitstream/handle/10139/5000/McDonough2011Thesis.pdf?sequence=1

$\bullet$ Factoring polynomials in the ring of formal power series over $\mathbb Z$; Daniel Birmajer, Juan B. Gil, Michael D. Weiner

https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1425

http://php.scripts.psu.edu/users/m/d/mdw8/class/polyfactor.pdf

$\bullet$ Factoring formal power series over principal ideal domains; Jesse Elliott

https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4860

https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-2014-05903-5