# Classification of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to find the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$.

> $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ is the ring of formal power series with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Addition and multiplication are defined analogously to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

So far, I've got the following. Suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$. Note that, $\mathfrak{p}^c = \mathfrak{p} \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. So we consider the following two cases -

**Case 1**: $\mathfrak{p} \cap \mathbb{Z} = (p)$

Then note that

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[[X]]}{\mathfrak{p}} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[[X]]/(p)}{\mathfrak{p}/(p)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z_p}[[X]]}{\mathfrak{\overline{p}}}$$

But $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field and we precisely know all the ideals of $\mathbb{F}[[X]]$ when $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. So $\mathfrak{\overline{p}} = (X)$ or $(0)$. Hence $\mathfrak{p} = (p, X)$ or $(p)$ where $p$ is a prime number.

**Case 2**: $\mathfrak{p} \cap \mathbb{Z} = (0)$

I have not able to work-out this case completely but nonetheless, here is what I have uptil now (assume $\mathfrak{p} \neq (0)$) -

- If $X \in \mathfrak{p}$ then $\mathfrak{p} = (X)$ because if $f \in \mathfrak{p}$ then let $$f(X) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n X^n = a_0 + Xg(X)$$ where $g(X) = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n X^{n-1}$. Hence $$a_0 = f(X) - Xg(X) \in \mathfrak{p} \implies a_0 = 0 \implies f(X) = Xg(X) \implies \mathfrak{p} = (X)$$
- If $X \not \in \mathfrak{p}$ then let $0 \neq f \in \mathfrak{p}$. Then $$f(X) = X^kg(X) = X^k\left(\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n X^n\right)$$
  for some $k \geq 0$, such that $a_0 \neq 0$. This implies, $g(X) \in \mathfrak{p}$ and so $a_0 \neq \pm 1$. I don't know how to proceed further.

Besides, the only non-tirival map $\mathbb{Z}[[X]] \to \mathbb{Z}$, I can think of is $f(X) \mapsto f(0)$. Yet I don't see why $(X+2)$ is not a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ (or is it?)

Comment: There are a couple of references about $\mathbb Z[[X]]$ here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2252938/660 - I'm not sure they're helpful, but I wanted to mention them to you just in case...

Comment: I don't there is a good (known) answer to this. The primes not contracting to zero are easy, and the primes contracting to zero are really hard.

Comment: Another MSE reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274803/primes-in-a-power-series-ring

Comment: According to this [paper](http://repository.library.csuci.edu/bitstream/handle/10139/5000/McDonough2011Thesis.pdf?sequence=1) (Page 30), don't we get all prime ideals to be - $(0)$, $(p)$, $(X)$,  $(p, X)$, $(f)$, where f is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$